# How do I install python_ldap on 64 bit windows 7?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-ldap

I'm using python 2.7.6 and in my code I have a line:

```
    import psycopg2.extensions
```

which I've installed using pip. Next, my editor tells me, that psycopg2 requires python_ldap=2.4.19.
However, in the PyPI repository, there's only a 32 bit version, which doesn't work, since my Windows is 64 bit.
There's a 64 bit version of python_ldap=2.4.28, avaliable [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap), however running

```
    pip install python_ldap-2.4.28-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

in the windows command line returns

```
    python_ldap-2.4.28-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

in red, which I guess is an error meassage.
So, in the end, what should I do to have the package installed on my laptop?

Answer (score 20):

For anyone who's facing this, I solved this problem by installing the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap.

Cheers.

EDIT: I did this on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine, but I presume the same solution applies to Windows 7.

Comment: I guess the is the only option to install python-ldap in Win 7. Make sure you choose the binary version matching your version of Python install.

Answer (score 6):

$ python --version
**Python 3.6.0**

pip install --only-binary :all: python_ldap-3.1.0-**cp36-cp36m**-win_amd64.whl

Make sure you choose the .whl file version matching the python install version

```
pip install --only-binary :all: python_ldap-3.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Processing c:\users\sthomas05\downloads\python_ldap-3.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in c:\users\sthomas05\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from python-ldap==3.1.0) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5 in c:\users\sthomas05\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from python-ldap==3.1.0) (0.2.4)
Installing collected packages: python-ldap
Successfully installed python-ldap-3.1.0
```

Comment: I could not get the 3.1 version mentioned above, but i was able to use different version and got it working. 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyldap

download 
pyldap-2.4.45-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

pip install --only-binary :all: pyldap-2.4.45-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the official [website](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/installing.html#windows) the unofficial package from on Christoph [Gohlke’s page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap) should work.
Latest update is from 3rd of July, so it seems to be pretty up to date.

Comment: those libraries are useless, as the last python version there is 3.4

Comment: the last python version there is 3.11. The 3.4 refers to the open-ldap version